# Error in setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar) in mainActivity java

Tags: java, android, toolbar

There is an error while working in android studio in main activity java.
The error is saying can't resolve the symbol in "setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)" and It is built in code. I tried importing implementations but the issue still occurs. And there is no quick fixes for this error showing. What should I do to solve the error.

```
package com.example.learn1;

import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.util.*;

import androidx.navigation.NavController;
import androidx.navigation.Navigation;
import androidx.navigation.ui.AppBarConfiguration;
import androidx.navigation.ui.NavigationUI;

import com.example.learn1.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;

import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void login(View view)
    {
        EditText usernameEditText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.usernameEditText);
        EditText passwordEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordEditText);
        Log.i("Info", "Button Pressed");

    }
    public void clickFunction(View view)
    {
        EditText usernameEditText= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.usernameEditText);


        Log.i("Values" ,usernameEditText.getText().toString());
        Log.i("info","Button pressed");
    }
    private AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration;
    private ActivityMainBinding binding;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater());
        setContentView(binding.getRoot());


       setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar);

        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
        appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(navController.getGraph()).build();
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, appBarConfiguration);

        binding.fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment_content_main);
        return NavigationUI.navigateUp(navController, appBarConfiguration)
                || super.onSupportNavigateUp();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have to use

```
    setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar.getRoot());
```

instead of

```
    setSupportActionBar(binding.toolbar)
```

since `getRoot()` will actually return `View` declared in `res/layout/toolbar-like.xml` file rather than its reference in `activity.xml`:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/databinding/ViewDataBinding#getroot